# ORA-01536: Out of space error when doing CTAS

Tags: oracle, tablespaces, ctas

I have two schemas `A` and `B`. I'm trying to copy over table `B.users` to `A`. I've followed these steps:

Run in schema `B`:

```
GRANT ALL ON users TO A;
```

Run in schema `A`:

```
CREATE TABLE users AS (SELECT * FROM B.users);
```

This gives the error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'A'
>   01536. 00000 -  "space quota exceeded for tablespace '%s'"
>   *Cause:    The space quota for the segment owner in the tablespace has
>              been exhausted and the operation attempted the creation of a
>              new segment extent in the tablespace.
>   *Action:   Either drop unnecessary objects in the tablespace to reclaim
>              space or have a privileged user increase the quota on this
>              tablespace for the segment owner.

The error seems to be misleading and I suspect something else is the problem here, because the users table has only some 1000 users or so and the tablespace in question has 2 GB allocated to it, all of it free. Furthermore trying to copy just a single row also gives the same error:

```
CREATE TABLE users AS (SELECT * FROM B.users where rownum < 2);
```

However, copying schema without any data succeeds:

```
CREATE TABLE users AS (SELECT * FROM B.users where rownum = -1); /* This works */
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user `A` must be running out of quota(or you might have forgotten to assign quota) on assigned tablespace.

> The error seems to be misleading and I suspect something else is the problem here, because the users table has only some 1000 users or so and the tablespace in question has 2 GB allocated to it, all of it free.

Error is self-describing. It's stating that quota for the user(owner of the segment) has exceeded.

> However, copying schema without any data succeeds:
>
> `CREATE TABLE users AS (SELECT * FROM B.users where rownum = -1); /* This works */`

To execute this command user don't need quota because its simply creating an empty table whose definition will be stored in data dictionary.

Increase the quota for the user `A` as shown below.

```
SQL> conn sys as sysdba
SQL> alter user A quota <size> on <tablespace>;
```